# looking for cheap, USA-based, shared, ASP.NET 4 hosting

Tags: web-hosting, asp.net, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Actually I did find a solid company in Poland, where I live, but the problem is I will need USA-based server IP because google gives SEO bonus based on server location and I expect most of the visitors to come from the USA. The webpage in question will be tiny and niche so I don't want to overpay. Also, is there any reliable way of making sure I will get a USA-based host?  For instance I just looked at godaddy.com and they say their servers are in Europe - probably they think that's what I want :).

REGARDINDG IP LOCATION INFLUENCE ON GOOGLE RANK - my sources:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXt23AXlJJU

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=keIzr3eWK8I

Comment: "google gives SEO bonus based on server location" Citation needed

Comment: @ZippyV: see the links.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to actually contact GoDaddy support and ask about choosing where you end up. They do have multiple data centers(US, Europe and Asia), but that doesn't necessarily mean each of them actually supports all of their various hosting options. There's definitely a chance they offered you European servers based on geolocating you, but there's also a chance that's just where they put all of whatever hosting plan you were looking at.
Someone actually working there will be able to respond to your specific case most accurately. You also might find something in their community support forum.

This is going to apply in general. Not counting higher-end VPS/dedicated host offerings(you said cheap) most don't bother even mentioning where their servers are because the people signing up probably don't know or care what a data center *is* in the first place and it'd just be distracting information.